# How to replace &ldquo; &ldquo with double quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to do something like this:

```
 s = s.replace(/(&rdquo;)/g, '"'); // need to replace with double quotes
 s = s.replace(/(&ldquo;)/g, '"'); // need to replace with double quotes
 s = s.replace(/(&rsquo;)/g, "'"); // need to replace with single quotes
```

But for me this does not work. I tried all the ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Unicode values in replace:

```
s = s.replace(/\u201C|\u201D/g, '"');  // for “ or ”
s = s.replace(/\u2019/g, "'");         // for ’
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uM2fY/

Answer (score 3):

So we open console, and see:

```
>>> 'test&rqduo;foo'.replace(/&rqduo;/g, '\"' );
test"foo
```

and with braces:

```
>>> 'test&rqduo;foo'.replace(/(&rqduo;)/g, '\"' );
test"foo
```

Everything work just like you thought. Please, check your input strings.